# What does the argument/parameter “dynamic_padding” do exactly in the Alacritty terminal emulator?

Tags: linux, terminal

The [Alacritty config file](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/8681f71084894db6d1e258be17db1f80bb669314/alacritty.yml#L52) lists an argument/parameter `dynamic_padding` to:

> “Spread additional padding evenly around the terminal content.”

What exactly is this “additional padding?” Where would it come from?

Answer (score 2):

That dynamic padding is extra space around the boundaries of the actual terminal area. It's opaque and the color of your default terminal background. Programs you run won't be able to display anything there.

In the illustration below, Alacritty is running neovim. The lighter shades of grey are the terminal; Neovim has full control of that. The dark black padding around the edges is `dynamic_padding`, and defaults to the color of your terminal background. Neovim, and any other program you run, can't modify the content/color of this padding.

[image: padding]

Comment: Thanks. So how does dynamic padding differ from the ordinary padding option (with the ***x*** and ***y*** settings)?

Comment: Well, it takes the ordinary padding add computes an additional value using a special function designed to even the padding spatially https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/8681f71084894db6d1e258be17db1f80bb669314/alacritty_terminal/src/term/mod.rs#L188